# Malformed json causing java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to build a simple stickers app for whatsapp with android studio. I don't know why it says that there is a mailformed json file.
this is the error on logcat (might be something else, like bad name of the apk or some other error)

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.javiermilei.stickers, PID: 5574
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.javiermilei.stickers.StickerContentProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: contents.json file has some issues: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 17 column 10
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5923)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5490)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5429)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1564)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: contents.json file has some issues: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 17 column 10
        at com.javiermilei.stickers.StickerContentProvider.readContentFile(StickerContentProvider.java:149)
        at com.javiermilei.stickers.StickerContentProvider.getStickerPackList(StickerContentProvider.java:155)
        at com.javiermilei.stickers.StickerContentProvider.onCreate(StickerContentProvider.java:90)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5920)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5490) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5429) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1564) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
     Caused by: android.util.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 17 column 10
        at android.util.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1159)
        at android.util.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:838)
        at android.util.JsonReader.nextInObject(JsonReader.java:660)
        at android.util.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:349)
        at android.util.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:319)
        at com.javiermilei.stickers.ContentFileParser.readStickers(ContentFileParser.java:145)
        at com.javiermilei.stickers.ContentFileParser.readStickerPack(ContentFileParser.java:106)
        at com.javiermilei.stickers.ContentFileParser.readStickerPacks(ContentFileParser.java:47)
        at com.javiermilei.stickers.ContentFileParser.parseStickerPacks(ContentFileParser.java:28)
        at com.javiermilei.stickers.StickerContentProvider.readContentFile
```

I can't find the error here is the file supposedly there is a mailform at line 17 column 10 (as per logcat)

```
{
  "android_play_store_link": "",
  "ios_app_store_link": "",
  "sticker_packs": [
    {
      "identifier": "1",
      "name": "Javier Milei",
      "publisher": "QBSLC Inc.",
      "tray_image_file": "tray_Milei.png",
      "publisher_email":"",
      "publisher_website": "",
      "privacy_policy_website": "",
      "license_agreement_website": "",
      "stickers": [
        {
          "image_file": "01_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "02_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "03_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "04_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "05_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "06_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "07_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "08_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "09_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "10_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "11_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "12_Milei.webp",
        },
        {
          "image_file": "13_Milei.webp",
        }

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ finds an error on the same line. I think the trailing comma is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a JSON is valid or not,
Use this website for example: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

In your case, you have a invalid comma in your sticker entry.

Comment: And these commas repeat at each line

Comment: thanks everyone!! I was able to build the app on android studio